# Chat search fails to load page 2

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, chat

I can't seem to be able to load page 2 of some chat searches. For example this one: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=chat+search+sucks&user=46642&room=10. I just get the cat workin on mah problemz.

With some different searches I can load page 2. This one https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=blah&user=46642&room=10 is an example that works.

I confirmed that this is not on my side, because [other users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2001828#2001828) seem to get the Oops page too.

I hope the cat that is working on my problem will be able to solve it :)

[image: The cat]

Comment: Seems to be any page except the first. Sadly it looks like they don't embed the error message in the chat error page

Comment: I'm investigating, but it seems to work fine for me; is this still happening?

Comment: oh, I see it; that's odd... as "me", it works fine, as an anon user, it times out. Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: @Marc, Yep, just checked and it still shows the Oops page. I'm logged in, FWIW.

Comment: indeed; it must be something to do with access checks; looking...

Comment: @Marc I added an example where I can access the second page. Maybe that can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the techie-folk, this was due to parameter-sniffing; the database server had prepared a query plan based on some early typical parameters that was not representative of all the rooms on the site, meaning: for different values, the plan was inappropriate and timed out.

This has been solved by the "dammit will you just *work*!" clause in SQL server, aka

```
option (optimize for unknown)
```

it should now work